# ___lldb_unnamed_function in a symbolicated crash log

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode5, crash-log

I have a crash log produced on an iPhone OS 7.0.4. I have the appropriate .app and .dSYM files. When I symbolicate the crash log with Xcode 5, it shows me something like this:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyProject          0x001df98a ___lldb_unnamed_function6108$$MyProject + 42
1   MyProject          0x001e0c49 ___lldb_unnamed_function6119$$MyProject + 9
2   MyProject          0x002928d5 ___lldb_unnamed_function8439$$MyProject + 13
3   MyProject          0x0027fa1f ___lldb_unnamed_function8072$$MyProject + 287
4   MyProject          0x0028e657 ___lldb_unnamed_function8368$$MyProject + 27
5   MyProject          0x002888d1 ___lldb_unnamed_function8257$$MyProject + 201
```

When I symbolicate the crash log with Xcode 4, it produces the right result - it shows me the classes and methods from my application where the crash has occurred. There are no anonymous blocks involved in the stack trace.

How come Xcode 4 and Xcode 5 produce different symbolicated crash logs? When I run the symbolicatecrash script in verbose mode, it shows identical results for both Xcode's: they match the correct .app and .dSYM files and both finish with these lines:

```
done.
1 binary images were found.
Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/atos -arch armv7 -l 0xd1000 -o '<PATH>/MyProject.app/MyProject' 0x002928d5 0x002888d1 0x001e0c49 0x0027fa1f 0x000d8f27 0x001df98a 0x0028e657 | 
got symbolicator for <PATH>/MyProject.app/MyProject, base address 4000
```

Comment: Does `xcrun -f atos` show the path to the correct up to date Xcode installation?

Comment: @Kerni Yes, I tested it on machines where Xcode 5 is the single Xcode installation. There's also one machine with Xcode 4 and 5, xcrun shows the path to Xcode 5 there too.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and solved it by calculating address for ___lldb_unnamed_function from [iOS crash reports: atos not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected) post.

After that run:

xcrun atos -arch armv7(s) -o Xyz.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/xyz **Calculated_Address**

Answer (score 1):

I have been having issues symbolicating with xcode 5 as well

so I resorted to symbolicating my symbols manually using atos.

```
atos -arch armv7 -o myApp.app/myApp 0x178e9e
 -- 
Warning: /usr/bin/atos is moving and will be removed from a future OS X release.
It is now available in the Xcode developer tools to be invoked via: `xcrun atos`
To silence this warning, pass the '-d' command-line flag to this tool.
 -- 
AFJSONEncode (in myApp) + 434
```

the warning looked interesting so i decided to try xcrun atos

```
xcrun atos -arch armv7 -o myApp.app/myApp 0x178e9e
___lldb_unnamed_function6926$$myApp (in myApp) + 434
```

which is giving me an unnamed function.

so my guess is that Xcode 5 is using xcrun atos, which has a bug.

using atos did help me diagnose the problem and patch a fix. I do not have Xcode 4 installed. perhaps you can verify if Xcode 4 produces the same results as atos? I followed the instructions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970959/how-to-manually-symbolicate-a-crash-log-with-atos)

I'm in a good mind to write a script to symbolicate crash logs :/

Comment: I had to use `arm64` to force symbols to build for all arm categories. It gave the false error "armv7 not found" until I did that, since my dylib contained symbols fro all archs.

Answer (score 0):

You must have created build with xcode 4.6 and may be you upgraded to xcode 5 now. you need to set your xcode developer directory to xcode 4.6 developer directory for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As I discovered in the comments for [Cannot replicate Apple iOS app review crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126764/cannot-replicate-apple-ios-app-review-crash) the beta of Xcode 5.1 solves this problem. I'm now getting proper symbols for from my crash reports.

Answer (score 0):

I got this kind of issues when i forgot to quit [Spark Inspector](http://www.sparkinspector.com) when debugging our application on an `iOS 5` device (like the `original iPad`).

Answer (score -1):

Had same ___lldb_unnamed_function symbols in crash log. 
You can get the actual classes and methods from [KSCrash](https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash) (Third Party iOS Crash Reporter ) where the crash has occurred.
Supports uncaught C++ exceptions too!